# Hotel Booking Integration Using Catalook

Tags: dotnetnuke

We want to add a hotel booking system to a DNN site. This concept is discussed [here](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/forums/threadid/412756/scope/posts/module-for-hotel-online-reservation).

We tried to implement hotel booking using catalook, but the catalook store did not find all hotel related fields, like number of bed rooms, beds, bath rooms, accommodates, property type, amenities, etc. We are not clear how to add a custom field in the catalook product detail page for filtering things.

We are using latest catalook version 6.9.1 in DNN 7.4.1. We need additional fields when adding product (hotel) management and we are not sure about booking hotel system using catalook module. Can anyone assist me to move forward for configuring online reservation system using catalook module?

Comment: We generally recommend that questions are not marked as urgent here, since all readers are volunteers, and they tend to answer at their leisure. As to the question it is hard to work out what help you need - is it particularly how to add a custom field in the product detail page?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new rentable or configurable product. Then under the attributes of the product you can add options such as extra room etc along with prices for each add-on. The manual explains everything. The tabs under the product edit have all the functionalities you need.

Comment: Thanks,

But i need one more doubt

I have created custom filed is "bedrooms" using product attribute
product attribute value assigned bedrooms=7
as well as add Another Product bedroom is=4 
but it shoud be changed previous bedrooms 7 replaced 4
how to add different value same field

Comment: @Jay You can find the formulas in the manual. Usually they add/subtract price depending on the extras. So you can have a+b=5 or a+c=6 etc. It's all in the manual. Look for the formuals